# Notify user to login on clear the browser cache

Tags: javascript

Hi
I am working on a web-application which deals which jQuery,Javascript,Html as a part of UI.
we have login authentication which will ask for username and password.
so my question is how to notify the user automatically to login into my application, when user will clear the cache.
for example: do login into facebook. after login clear the cache of browser. instantly you will get a notification to login again. please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save login information in a cookie. When it's no longer present - redirect user to your login page.

Comment: don't mind,can you please explain this on brief? please give me an example.I am using Session-stroage. there i have saved the username and password.

Comment: @RakeshMahapatro Basically sessions map to server side and cookies map to client side [browser]. For the first time when user logs into ur system, store the user info in a cookie [Ex: Check box with Remember be on this computer] and start a session at server side. So, on every request to your system - browser manages to send that cookie info which you can access from your server side code. If the detail you get didn't match your requirement then end the user session and ask him to log in again.